# Adding tooltips in textarea with awesome tag

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm facing a problem in react project. in this, I have to add tooltip in textarea  tag

I'm getting tooltips when i replaced textarea tag with input tag but the tag must be textarea

```html
<section>

  <label className="label">Help Text</label>
  <label className="input"> <i className="icon-append fa fa-file-text-o"></i>

<textarea row="3" style={{minWidth: "100%"}} id="cHelpText" type="text"  className="custom-scroll" onChange={this.handleChange} ></textarea>

<b className="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i className="fa fa-file-text-o txt-color-teal"></i></b>

</label>

</section>
```

Comment: here i'm correcting myself,                                                                                                                        we can able to see tooltips just by replacing className="input" to className="textarea".                                                                                                       thank you so much for the support

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of using Tooltips which require a hover state (and hence a mouse) to use the placeholder attribute instead, and then it works on mobile and desktop. It is then also visible on page load which is more helpful - ultimately the intention here is to guide a user.

```
<textarea row="3" style={{minWidth: "100%"}} placeholder="help text here" onChange={this.handleChange} ></textarea>
```

That would be more elegant. You do not need a type="text" on a textarea either.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the textarea in a div and then show or hide the tooltip on hover -

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

<div class="tooltip">
 <textarea></textarea>
 <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is textarea ?